# Return value from PYQt slot of QwebView to main window widget (PYQt python)

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qwidget, qwebview

i am building a desktop application using PyQt python which has a QwebBrowser. now i am running some function using javascript which is returning a value say abc as per following example.

```
class QWebView(QWebView):

 def contextMenuEvent(self,event):  
      menu = QMenu()
      self.actionShowXpath = menu.addAction("Show Xpath")  
      QObject.connect(self.actionShowXpath,SIGNAL("triggered()"),self,SLOT("slotshowxpath()"))

      menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint(event.x(),event.y())))   

      @pyqtSlot()
      def slotshowxpath(self):
           frame.evaluateJavaScript("var abc = function get()");
           result = frame.evaluateJavaScript("abc").toString()

            **some code code to put result in QLineEdit Widget**
            # something like below
            # xpath.setText(result)


def window():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = QtGui.QWidget()
   web = QWebView(w)
   web.load(QUrl("http://www.indiatimes.com/"))
   web.show()

   xpath = QtGui.QLineEdit("", w)
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
     window()
```

now, i want to put the value of abc in a QLineEdit widget("xpath") present in my application.please give me suggestion that how i can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [PySide. JavaScript. Execute js an get result as a pure text or html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20047805/2473979)

Comment: That's not how you call a function in js.

Comment: @salomonderossi thanks for the reference, but i want to know that how to put the value of result in the QLineEdit widget which is present in another def.??

Comment: @salomonderossi please help if you have any idea of this question

Comment: @7stud please take a look.

Comment: First, What version of Qt and PyQt are you using?

Comment: ('Qt version:', '4.8.6') , ('PyQt version:', '4.10.4')

Comment: @7stud do you need some other details?

Comment: @7stud i request you to add bounty on this question so that i can get the solution of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't work up an example because QtWebkit has been removed from Qt 5.6, but if the problem you are having is because you don't have a reference to your QLineEdit, then pass the QLineEdit to your QWebView class's `__init__()` function:

```
def start_app():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = QtGui.QWidget()
    xpathInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(main_window)

    web_view = MyWebView(main_window, xpathInput)  #<===HERE
    web_view.load(QUrl("http://www.indiatimes.com/"))

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then in your QWebView class:

```
class MyWebView(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent, xpath_widget):
        #QWebView.__init__(parent)
        QWebView.__init__(self, parent)
        #or: super(MyWebView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.xpath_widget = xpath_widget

    def contextMenuEvent(self,event):  
        menu = QMenu()
        self.actionShowXpath = menu.addAction("Show Xpath") 

        #QObject.connect(
        #    self.actionShowXpath,
        #    SIGNAL("triggered()"),
        #    self,SLOT("slotshowxpath()")
        #)

        self.actionShowXpath.triggered.connect(self.show_xpath)

        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint(event.x(),event.y())))   

    #@pyqtSlot()
    def show_xpath(self):
        frame = ...
        frame.evaluateJavaScript("var abc = function get()");
        result = frame.evaluateJavaScript("abc").toString()

        #some code code to put result in QLineEdit Widget**
        self.xpath_widget.setText(result)
```

But I think a better way to organize your code would be to do something like this:

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.xpathInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.web_view = QWebView(self) 
        self.web_view.load(QUrl("http://www.indiatimes.com/"))

        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.actionShowXpath = self.menu.addAction("Show Xpath") 

        #QObject.connect(
        #    self.actionShowXpath,
        #    SIGNAL("triggered()"),
        #    self,SLOT("slotshowxpath()")
        #)

        self.actionShowXpath.triggered.connect(self.show_xpath)

        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint(event.x(),event.y())))

    def show_path(self):
        frame = ...
        result = frame.evaluateJavaScript("abc").toString()
        self.xpathInput.setText(result)


def start_app():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for the help buddy, i will try this and update you within a few hours

Comment: its showing me an error-                                                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "GUI-Test.py", line 91, in <module>
 window()
 File "GUI-Test.py", line 75, in window
    web = QWebView(w,xpath)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: @ricky rana, GUI programming is an intermediate to advanced topic in computer programming. It's clear that you are a python beginner. You are not ready for PyQt programs yet. Nevertheless, see the change I made.

Comment: you are right, i am new to python but don't worry i will be a good programmer like you soon, thanks for the help but sorry to say that its again showing the error -                                                                                                        File "GUI-Test.py", line 12, in __init__
    QWebView.__init__(parent)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with QWebView instance as first argument (got QWidget instance instead).

Comment: @ricky rana: `QWebView.__init__(self, parent)`.  Or, you might be able to use super(): `super(MyWebView, self).__init__(parent)`